# Microsoft Office 2007 Macro - Odd behavior. Cursor Jumps

Tags: vba, ms-office

I hope someone have some insight into this.

I have a check box on page 1 and when it's clicked, it will launch a macro & insert a value to a text box on page 10. Simple

The problem is, the script in the macro is looking for the value of another text box on page 5 to do some calculation. Whenever i do

```
text5value = Val(oFFld("Text5").Result)
```

or

```
If (Val(oFFld("Text5").Result) = "") Then
```

The cursor will suddenly move from page 1 to page 5. Very confusing to user.

This behavior happens whenever I try to get the value of a textbox. Wherever that textbox is in the current document, it will jump to it.

Please help

Comment: you did not mention which program you're using. Is it Word ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Screen Updating to false for the duration of the macro.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Not only will this hide the various screen jumps it is doing while the macro runs, the macro will also run faster if it doesn't have to constantly update the screen.